# 32 bit Qt app crashes randomly on Windows 7 x64

Tags: c++, windows, qt, crash

We have an old codebase which we develop using C++ Qt framework (v4.6.3) under Windows XP SP3. The app that is built with that codebase is working free of problems under Windows XP.

Upon customer request we deployed the app to Windows 7 x64 machines. After that we came across with random crash issues in release build when we try to start the app. App consumes nearly 2GB of memory when it crashes. If we change app compatibility to Windows XP SP3, the crash problem goes away. Also crash never happens in debug mode.

We collected some logs about crash issue. Below logs are given:
1. Windows log after app crashes.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: kmclient3.exe
  Application Version: 0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp: 55b72d4f
  Fault Module Name: KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.18409
  Fault Module Timestamp: 53159a86
  Exception Code: e06d7363
  Exception Offset: 0000c42d
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID: 1055
  Additional Information 1: 9c29
  Additional Information 2: 9c2952f45ffd526b51f7caf2e8b92e02
  Additional Information 3: e72c
  Additional Information 4: e72c8eab1d594c6991d297d4615a53d6
```

2.WinDbg log when we attach debugger after the app crashes.

```
** wait with pending attach

Symbol search path is: E:\Symbols  
Executable search path is:   
ModLoad: 01220000 014f7000     E:\YERLISINYAL09\YAZILIM\build\TKM_crash_test\kmclient3.exe  
ModLoad: 76dd0000 76f79000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll  
ModLoad: 76fb0000 77130000   ntdll.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`748f0000 00000000`7492f000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`74890000 00000000`748ec000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64win.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`74880000 00000000`74888000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wow64cpu.dll
ModLoad: 00000000`769f0000 00000000`76b00000   KERNEL32.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`74c30000 00000000`74c77000   KERNELBASE.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`596e0000 00000000`5971e000   UMEngx86.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`67000000 00000000`67211000   QtCore4.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`74ad0000 00000000`74bd0000   USER32.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`75310000 00000000`753a0000   GDI32.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`75100000 00000000`7510a000   LPK.dll   
ModLoad: 00000000`75a60000 00000000`75afd000   USP10.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`76920000 00000000`769cc000   msvcrt.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`74c90000 00000000`74d30000   ADVAPI32.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`76760000 00000000`76779000   SECHOST.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`75220000 00000000`75310000   RPCRT4.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`74950000 00000000`749b0000   SspiCli.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`74940000 00000000`7494c000   CRYPTBASE.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`754c0000 00000000`7561c000   ole32.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`757b0000 00000000`757e5000   WS2_32.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`74c80000 00000000`74c86000   NSI.dll   
ModLoad: 00000000`5a5a0000 00000000`5a62e000   MSVCP90.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`737f0000 00000000`73893000   MSVCR90.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`65000000 00000000`657a7000   QtGui4.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`749b0000 00000000`74a2b000   COMDLG32.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`757f0000 00000000`75847000   SHLWAPI.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`5ce00000 00000000`5ce84000   COMCTL32.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`75b00000 00000000`7674a000   SHELL32.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`76b10000 00000000`76b9f000   OLEAUT32.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`74bd0000 00000000`74c30000   IMM32.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`75120000 00000000`751ec000   MSCTF.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`5a560000 00000000`5a592000   WINMM.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`74810000 00000000`74861000   WINSPOOL.DRV  
ModLoad: 00000000`61000000 00000000`61055000   QtXml4.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`66000000 00000000`66045000   QtSvg4.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`64000000 00000000`640ea000   QtNetwork4.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`62000000 00000000`62031000   QtSql4.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`70c40000 00000000`70cc0000   UxTheme.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`70c20000 00000000`70c33000   dwmapi.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`753a0000 00000000`75423000   CLBCatQ.DLL  
ModLoad: 00000000`59540000 00000000`5969d000   inkobj.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`72110000 00000000`72124000   ATL.DLL  
ModLoad: 00000000`00e90000 00000000`01020000   gdiplus.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`732c0000 00000000`732d6000   CRYPTSP.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`73270000 00000000`732ab000   RSAENH.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`72f30000 00000000`72f3e000   RpcRtRemote.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`59530000 00000000`5953d000   TpcPS.DLL  
ModLoad: 00000000`10000000 00000000`10011000   qsqlmysql4.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`550e0000 00000000`55677000   libmysql.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`735f0000 00000000`735f8000   Secur32.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`72f90000 00000000`72fa0000   nlaapi.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`72f60000 00000000`72f70000   NAPINSP.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`72f40000 00000000`72f52000   PNRPNSP.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`734c0000 00000000`734fc000   MSWSOCK.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`72ee0000 00000000`72f24000   DNSAPI.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`72ed0000 00000000`72ed8000   WINRNR.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`6de50000 00000000`6de56000   rasadhlp.dll  
ModLoad: 00000000`734b0000 00000000`734b5000   WSHTCPIP.dll  
Break-in sent, waiting 30 seconds...  
WARNING: Break-in timed out, suspending.  
         This is usually caused by another thread holding the loader lock  
(1a2c.106c): Wake debugger - code 80000007 (first chance)  
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for KERNELBASE.dll -   
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x58:  
74c3c42d c9              leave  
0:000:x86> g  
** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll -   
ntdll!NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+0xa:  
00000000`76e22bba c3              ret  
0:004> g  
       ^ No runnable debuggees error in 'g'
```

3.WinDbg log when we open crash dump.

```
Loading Dump File [C:\Users\onur.ozcelik.BILISIM\Desktop\kmclient3.DMP]  
User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available  

Symbol search path is: E:\Symbols  
Executable search path is:   
Windows 7 Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (12 procs) Free x86 compatible  
Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS  
Machine Name:  
Debug session time: Tue Jul 28 10:46:30.000 2015 (GMT+3)  
System Uptime: 0 days 2:42:56.184  
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:02:46.000  
........................................................  
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ntdll.dll -   
eax=00000002 ebx=0000000b ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=00000002 edi=00407c58  
eip=76fd1f46 esp=036ffac4 ebp=036ffc24 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc  
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246  
ntdll!NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+0x12:  
76fd1f46 83c404          add     esp,4  
0:000> g  
       ^ No runnable debuggees error in 'g'
```

What causes the crash issue?
Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Logs seem to be not very informative. Could you imagine why your program may consume 2 GB of memory, I think it is not normal? May be you can add some more logging in these cases?

Comment: Find reproducible steps for the problem on the release build. Then generate pdb files for the release build and attach the debugger to running release process and do the aforementioned steps. (If using Visual Studio, you don't mention) Also, if an application works in a debug build, but fails in a release build, one of the compiler optimizations may be exposing a defect in the source code.

Comment: It's not unthinkable that it might be a bug in this old version of Qt. Perhaps you could try with the most recent version - Qt 4.8.7. Even if you're not licensed for it, you can try it, and if it fixes the problem, you can start bisecting the changes to zero in on the change that did fix it. Finally, you'll really need to run it in a debugger with symbols loaded and you have to examine the call stack to see what it's doing when it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simply means there is a bug in your program. Without seeing the code its hard to tell where. I would suggest using `cout` or `printf` or `qDebug()` to detect the last line upto where the code runs well. This will give you the area where error is occurring. This is how I resolved my bug in multi thread program. I would also suggest you to read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548/Surviving-the-Release-Version).

Comment: I accept the bug possibility. But why the bug disappear in Windows XP compatibility mode.

Comment: The same reason how the program runs fine under debug mode and crashes during release mode. Memory allocation is very much different in both the modes, also the memory is initialised with 0 in debug mode. In windows xp most probably the memory is allocated like the debug version in windows 7 (no one knows. It's closed source). Overall memory allocation is very much different in both the windows.

Comment: Best why to detect it by using `cout` or `qDebug()`. Please read the article given in the link.

Comment: We tracked the bug with cout in release build and found that an uninitialized integer is responsible.